# MySQL dump import bug

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I tried to import mysql dump of 3GB at that point my C:\ drive had 70GB free space. Once I started my dump gradually C:\ drive became full and import also failed. I am using maria db 10.9 version. Can any one help me to fix this issue.

This is my.ini file

```
[mysqld]
datadir=C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.9/data
port=3306
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2019M
max_allowed_packet=10G
innodb_file_per_table
[client]
port=3306
plugin-dir=C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.9/lib/plugin
```

Comment: It might be [MDEV-28240](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28240) if you aren't using 10.6.10+. Having a MariaDB 10.9 looks suspicious when you say you are using 10.6.

Comment: Please read [ask] and write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title.

Comment: @danblack it was a typo and I have updated the version in question to 10.9